# How to group g elements in D3?

Tags: d3.js

Say for example I have a g element that contains a rect and text :

```
var cells = innercanvas
.selectAll(".newcell")
.data(treemap)
.enter()
.append("g")
.attr("class", "newcell");

 cells
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", function (d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr("y", function (d) {
      return d.y;
    })
    .attr("id", "rectangle")
    .attr("width", function (d) {
      return d.dx;
    })
    .attr("height", function (d) {
      return d.dy;
    })
    .style("fill", function (d) {
      return d.children ? cfg.color(d.name) : 'none';
    })
    .attr("stroke", "#000000")
    .attr('pointer-events', 'all')

cells
.append("text")
.attr("x", function (d) {
  return d.x + d.dx / 2;
})
.attr("y", function (d) {
  return d.y + d.dy / 2;
})
.attr('dy', '.95em')
.attr("text-anchor", "middle")
.text(function (d) { return d.children ? d.name : null })
```

I want to add a parent g element that groups `cells` based on their common name. For example ,

```
var parent = d3.selectAll("cells").attr("groupBy",function(d){ return d.children? d.name : null;})
```

This is so that I can display the parent name as a header for these common cells.

Comment: When you say 'display the parent name as a header' -- where do you want to display it? It's not all that easy to do what you're asking, but there are almost certainly other ways to achieve the same goal.

Comment: have a look at `d3.nest`, and based on the object you have generate the parent groups and the child rect groups. why do all the `rect` elements have the same **id**, no need to set `.attr('pointer-events', 'all')`

Comment: @ialarmedalien I want to display it on my treemap visualization. So I want to group all the rects which have the same parent name and put a header on top of it.

Comment: @rioV8 My data structure already has nesting and I have grouped it according to the parents name. Ex : My "States" field all have the same "Country" parent. My problem now is I want to visualize it on my treemap. How do I go about?

Comment: have a look at https://bl.ocks.org/bricedev/0d95074b6d83a77dc3ad and see how they create the child rects based on the datum of the parents, and from the child you can get the parent node datum `d3.select(d3.select(this).node().parentNode).datum()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nodes don't have to be grouped together physically to be able to group them to apply a label or highlight them. At present, the code you are using produces a `g` element for each parent node, with a `rect` that provides the colour fill and a blank `text` element. The child nodes are then overlaid on this parent node with a black `stroke` along the edges and a `text` node with the country name.

If you want to be able to highlight all the elements that have the same parent and put a header on the element, you can do it a couple of ways:

- alter existing elements to show a header
- create an overlay with the same dimensions as the parent node to display a header

#### Altering existing elements

To be able to do this, we first need to be able to identify parent nodes and their children. One way to do this is by giving nodes classes according to their position in the hierarchy and their data content. Here's one possible way to do this:

```
var cells = innercanvas
.selectAll(".newcell")
.data(treemap)
.enter()
.append("g")
.attr("class", function (d,i) {
  return 'newcell _' + i       // i provides a unique identifier for each node 
  + ' cell-level-' + d.depth   // cell-level-0 for root, cell-level-1, cell-level-2, etc 
  + ( d.name ? ' ' + safe_name(d.name) : '' ) // if d.name exists, use the 'safe' version
  + ( ! d.children
    ? ' leaf'                  // d has no children => it's a leaf node
    : (d.depth === 0
      ? ' root'                // d.depth = 0 => it's the root node
      : ' internal '));        // has children, depth > 0 => internal node
})

// strips non-alphanumeric characters out of `name` strings, replaces with _
function safe_name (txt) {
  return txt.replace(/\W/g, '_');
}
```

The SVG `g` elements now look like this:

[image: treemap SVG elements with extra class goodness]

Now we can easily access the parent node for any country name `c.name` by using

```
d3.select('.internal.' + safe_name(c.name))
```

or (e.g.) the `text` elements of the leaf nodes for the country using

```
d3.selectAll('.leaf.' + safe_name(c.name) + ' text')
```

We can then use CSS to show or hide text elements, `rect` strokes, etc.; e.g.

```js
var bool = false;
var toggle = d3.select('#toggle')
  .on('click', toggleSvg);
  
function toggleSvg() {
    bool = !bool;
    d3.selectAll('.Cyprus')
      .classed('highlightAll', bool);
}
```

```css
.newcell text {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.newcell.leaf rect {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 0.5px;
}

.oversize {
  display: none;
}

.internal text {
  opacity: 0
}

.internal.highlightAll text {
  opacity: 1
}

.highlightAll.leaf rect {
  opacity: 0.1
}

.highlightAll.leaf text {
  opacity: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<p><a id="toggle" href='#'>Toggle Cyprus highlighting</a></p>

<svg width="186" height="77">
      <g transform="translate(-30.1234, -258.33)">
        <g class="newcell _2331 cell-level-1 Cyprus internal ">
          <rect x="30.123480134121516" y="258.33086334171067" width="185.81893466750355" height="76.6094615363257" style="fill: rgb(100, 200, 75);"></rect>
          <title>Cyprus</title>
          <text x="123.0329474678733" y="296.63559410987354" dy=".35em" text-anchor="middle">Cyprus</text>
        </g>
        <g class="newcell _2332 cell-level-2 Cyprus leaf">
          <rect x="40.12348013412152" y="268.33086334171067" width="31.51365155392795" height="23.97574841366901" style="fill: none;"></rect>
          <title>Cyprus</title>
          <text x="55.88030591108549" y="280.3187375485452" dy=".35em" text-anchor="middle" class="oversize">Cyprus</text>
        </g>
        <g class="newcell _2333 cell-level-2 Cyprus leaf">
          <rect x="40.12348013412152" y="292.30661175537968" width="31.51365155392795" height="32.633713122656687" style="fill: none;"></rect>
          <title>Cyprus</title>
          <text x="55.88030591108549" y="308.62346831670802" dy=".35em" text-anchor="middle" class="oversize">Cyprus</text>
        </g>
        <g class="newcell _2334 cell-level-2 Cyprus leaf">
          <rect x="71.637131688049465" y="268.33086334171067" width="55.48181226963859" height="56.60946153632569" style="fill: none;"></rect>
          <title>Cyprus</title>
          <text x="99.37803782286876" y="296.63559410987354" dy=".35em" text-anchor="middle">Cyprus</text>
        </g>
        <g class="newcell _2335 cell-level-2 Cyprus leaf">
          <rect x="127.11894395768805" y="268.33086334171067" width="78.823470843937" height="56.60946153632569" style="fill: none;"></rect>
          <title>Cyprus</title>
          <text x="166.53067937965655" y="296.63559410987354" dy=".35em" text-anchor="middle">Cyprus</text>
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
```

#### Creating an overlay

This will duplicate an existing parent node on top of the treemap.

Add a new `g` element to the treemap with `rect` and `text` nodes as children:

```
var highlightG = canvas.append('g')
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + cfg.margin.left + "," + cfg.margin.top + ")")
    .append('g')
    .classed('highlighter', true)
    .attr('opacity',0);
highlightG.append('rect');
highlightG.append('text');
```

We can use the data from an existing parent node to set the appropriate position and size for the `rect` element and the content for the `text` element.

```
var d = d3.select('.internal.Cyprus').datum();
highlightG.select('rect')
  .attr("x", d.x)
  .attr("y", d.y)
  .attr("width", d.dx)
  .attr("height", d.dy)

highlightG
  .select("text")
  .attr("x", d.x + d.dx / 2 )
  .attr("y", d.y + d.dy / 2 )
  .attr('dy', '.35em')
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text(function () {
    return d.name;
  })
```

```js
d3.select('.internal.Cyprus').property('__data__', {
depth: 1,
dx: 185.81893466750355,
dy: 76.6094615363257,
name: "Cyprus",
value: 446770,
x: 30.123480134121516,
y: 258.33086334171067
});
var opacity = 1;
var highlightG = d3.select('svg')
  .append('g')
  .attr("transform", "translate(-30.1234, -258.33)")
  .append('g')
  .classed('highlighter', true)
  .attr('opacity', 0);
highlightG.append('rect');
highlightG.append('text');

d3.select('#toggle')
  .on('click', function() {
    var d = d3.select('.internal.Cyprus').datum();
    highlightG.attr('opacity', opacity);
    highlightG.select('rect')
      .attr("x", d.x)
      .attr("y", d.y)
      .attr("width", d.dx)
      .attr("height", d.dy)

    highlightG
      .select("text")
      .attr("x", d.x + d.dx / 2)
      .attr("y", d.y + d.dy / 2)
      .attr('dy', '.35em')
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function() {
        return d.name;
      })
    opacity = opacity ? 0 : 1;
  });
```

```css
.newcell text {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.newcell.leaf rect {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 0.5px;
}

.oversize {
  display: none;
}

.internal text {
  opacity: 0
}

.highlighter rect {
  fill: #000;
  fill-opacity: 0.7;
  stroke: deepskyblue;
  stroke-width: 5px;
}
.highlighter text {
  fill: deepskyblue;
  opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<p><a id="toggle" href='#'>Activate Cyprus overlay</a></p>

<svg width="186" height="77">
      <g transform="translate(-30.1234, -258.33)">
        <g class="newcell _2331 cell-level-1 Cyprus internal ">
          <rect x="30.123480134121516" y="258.33086334171067" width="185.81893466750355" height="76.6094615363257" style="fill: rgb(100, 200, 75);"></rect>
          <title>Cyprus</title>
          <text x="123.0329474678733" y="296.63559410987354" dy=".35em" text-anchor="middle">Cyprus</text>
        </g>
        <g class="newcell _2332 cell-level-2 Cyprus leaf">
          <rect x="40.12348013412152" y="268.33086334171067" width="31.51365155392795" height="23.97574841366901" style="fill: none;"></rect>
          <title>Cyprus</title>
          <text x="55.88030591108549" y="280.3187375485452" dy=".35em" text-anchor="middle" class="oversize">Cyprus</text>
        </g>
        <g class="newcell _2333 cell-level-2 Cyprus leaf">
          <rect x="40.12348013412152" y="292.30661175537968" width="31.51365155392795" height="32.633713122656687" style="fill: none;"></rect>
          <title>Cyprus</title>
          <text x="55.88030591108549" y="308.62346831670802" dy=".35em" text-anchor="middle" class="oversize">Cyprus</text>
        </g>
        <g class="newcell _2334 cell-level-2 Cyprus leaf">
          <rect x="71.637131688049465" y="268.33086334171067" width="55.48181226963859" height="56.60946153632569" style="fill: none;"></rect>
          <title>Cyprus</title>
          <text x="99.37803782286876" y="296.63559410987354" dy=".35em" text-anchor="middle">Cyprus</text>
        </g>
        <g class="newcell _2335 cell-level-2 Cyprus leaf">
          <rect x="127.11894395768805" y="268.33086334171067" width="78.823470843937" height="56.60946153632569" style="fill: none;"></rect>
          <title>Cyprus</title>
          <text x="166.53067937965655" y="296.63559410987354" dy=".35em" text-anchor="middle">Cyprus</text>
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
```

[I've created a .block](https://bl.ocks.org/ialarmedalien/26a5d48585cd5abc9d17886a77cefce2) with more comprehensive versions of these options.

You should be able to find some combination of these that you can use for your purposes.