# How to use the accessor function(d) to access the parent's value?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have this data : https://api.myjson.com/bins/xibvo

```
cells
  .append('title')
  .text(function (d) {
    return categoryKey + " : " + d.parent.name + "\n" + groupKey + " : " + d.name + "\n" + sizeKey + " : " + toCommas(d.value)
  });
```

I want the `d.parent.name` to display the parent for each data. The parents here are "Central","North","East",etc.

However, d.parent.name just returns cannot read property name of undefined. How do I use the acessor function to obtain the parent's name property? d.name returns the children's name property.

```
cells
  .append('title')
  .text(function (d) {
    return categoryKey + " : " + d.parent + "\n" + groupKey + " : " + d.name + "\n" + sizeKey + " : " + toCommas(d.value)
  });
```

If I use d.parent, I get [object Object] :
[image]

Comment: can you post a minimal but working version of your code? this is almost certainly because you are using a hierarchical data structure, but it would be easier to troubleshoot with the context included.

Comment: @ialarmedalien  I believe you have my project's code in your previous answers  here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52216447/how-to-group-g-elements-in-d3/52284717#52284717  . Basically I wanna add a title tooltip that displays the parent name for the data that I posted.

Comment: Ah, ok! It's better to add it to the question because not everyone has seen your other question.

Comment: maybe a simple search on SO for `d3 parent node`

Comment: @ialarmedalien Your answer was correct. Was just about to mark it as correct. However , the ternary operator version had a syntax error in it. Something about a missing ","

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're using hierarchical data and there is one case where `d.parent` isn't defined: the root node of your hierarchy. It's simple enough to fix, though: just check whether or not the parent node is present:

```
cells
  .append('title')
  .text(function (d) {
    if ( d.parent ) {
      return categoryKey + " : " + d.parent.name + "\n" + groupKey + " : " + d.name + "\n" + sizeKey + " : " + toCommas(d.value)
    }
    return d.name; // or whatever you want to do for the root node case
  });
```

You can compress this into a single line with a ternary if-else:

```
cells
  .append('title')
  .text(function (d) {
      return ( d.parent ? categoryKey + " : " + d.parent.name + "\n" : 'root node' )
      + groupKey + " : " + d.name + "\n" + sizeKey + " : " + toCommas(d.value)
    }
```

(code untested)